# Need advice about gameObject's rigidbody accesed by trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to make jump pads for my platformer game in unity using c#.

I'm stumped, how do I add force to other gameObject using triggers?

tried using `rb = gameobject.getcomponent<rigidbody>` in void start, Didnt work.

this is my code closest of what I expect

```
public float force = 1500f;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * force * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log("trigger!");
        }
    }
```

I expected if my player lands on the trigger it would launch him upwards, but it does not. I should also note that the console logs show "trigger!" so there is a mistake in and force.

No error messages.

Answer (score 4):

Time.deltaTime is a very small number and you don't need it when the function is called once. You can also try `other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * force, ForceMode.VelocityChange);`

You can read more about the AddForce method here: [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but you can try using your jump from the game. I mean you made the player jump if he presses space. You can reuse that.

That is my jump

```
private void Jump()
{
    if (grounded && readyToJump)
    {
        readyToJump = false;

        //Add jump forces
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce * 1.5f);
        rb.AddForce(normalVector * jumpForce * 0.5f);

        //If jumping while falling, reset y velocity.
        Vector3 vel = rb.velocity;
        if (rb.velocity.y < 0.5f)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, 0, vel.z);
        else if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, vel.y / 2, vel.z);

        Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
    }
}
```

Now you can make something like this

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    jumpPad JumpPad = collision.collider.GetComponent<jumpPad>();
    if (JumpPad != null)
    {
        //Add jump forces
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPadForce * 1.5f);
        rb.AddForce(normalVector * jumpPadForce * 0.5f);

        //If jumping while falling, reset y velocity.
        Vector3 vel = rb.velocity;
        if (rb.velocity.y < 0.5f)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, 0, vel.z);
        else if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(vel.x, vel.y / 2, vel.z);
    }
}
```

It is the simplest and quickest solution.
Just make a new jump force and called something like jump pad force.
That's it.